# JQuery Mobile - Hide Dropdown Option

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a drop down and I want to hide certain options, except when I use JQuery Mobiles enhancement version through data-native-menu="false", the option (Test 2) does not hide.  Going further, I will need to also update these dynamically as the user selects each option.

http://jsfiddle.net/AzdaR/

```
<select data-mini="true" data-native-menu="true">
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option style="display: none">Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>
</select>

<select data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false">
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option style="display: none">Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **custom select menus** your `select` DOM is replaced with other DOM elements on the build process. So you can't hide `option` elements and expect that your custom select menu also hides them.

However you can disable the option using `disabled="disabled"`.

```
<select data-mini="true" data-native-menu="false">
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>
</select>
```

[**See this working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AzdaR/1/)

Comment: Thanks and adding selectmenu("refresh", true); after a disable I was able to dynamically disable them.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to correct a misspelled word

```
"disabled="disabled">Test 2"
```